# Restore SQL Server Database from Local DBO File

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a backup DBO file from a remote database. I'm looking to restore one column on the remote database from the backup. I have no way to actually upload the  Is there a way via SQL Management Studio that I can join the two tables together (one from the backup and one from the remote server) so that I can restore?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Restore DB locally (on local SQL Server instance) and use **Import/Export Wizard** in Sql Server Management Studio to sent table to temporary location on remote serwer. After that, use T-SQL to restore column.